# Global macro definition in C++ per project

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, macros

Is there a way do define a global macro, like _DEBUG in VS 2013 to be global per project?
I want to use macro for conditional buld for different versions of application and avoid to include *.h.file containing the definition.

```
#define APP_VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define APP_VERSION_MINOR 0
#define APP_VERSION_HOTFIX 0
#define APP_VERSION_DEV a

#define APP_VER_STR_(s) #s
#define APP_VER_STR(s) APP_VER_STR_(s)

#define APP_VERSION APP_VER_STR(APP_VERSION_MAJOR) "." APP_VER_STR(APP_VERSION_MINOR) "." APP_VER_STR(APP_VERSION_HOTFIX) "." APP_VER_STR(APP_VERSION_DEV)
```

Comment: What build system are you using?  Does this approach seem reasonable for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the build system to pass the definitions to the C / C++ compiler using the -D syntax:

```
-DVERSION=2.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks, finally I am using the approach from the question and include the "appVer.h" as needed... (I want to be able to keep the version in source file and print the version if needed)